# $(Z_{11},+,\bullet )$ subfield

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I apologize for my English, I hope you understand.

> Does $(Z_{11},+,\bullet )$ have any subfield?

I've tried reading in my book and searching on the internet for answers.

What is the definition of if a subfield exists?

Comment: German *Körper*, which means *body*, is *field* in English in mathematics

Comment: It's subfield, since $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z$ is a .field. It is called a prime field. The answer is no, for reasons of characteristic.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you  mean subring, as you consider $\Bbb Z_{11}$ with two operations. Its a field and so can equivalently ask about subfields.

But $\Bbb Z_{11}$ is a prime field as $11$ is a prime and it has no proper subrings.

Answer (score 1):

The additive group of $\Bbb Z_{11}$ contains no proper nontrivial subgroup and so $\Bbb Z_{11}$ contains no proper subfield.